# Filtering out letters when using get-aduser not working in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to filter out letters in listing out usernames by using get-aduser. I get an error saying a parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name "filter".

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * |? { $_.samaccountname -match '^[a-j][A-J]' }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend building an LDAP filter for `sAMAccountName` that meets your requirements, rather than filtering after the fact with `Where-Object`. Example:

```
$charRange = ([Char] 'a'..[Char] 'j') | ForEach-Object { [Char] $_ }
$ldapFilter = "(&"
$charRange | ForEach-Object { $ldapFilter += "(!sAMAccountName=$_*)" }
$ldapFilter += ")"
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter $ldapFilter
```

Basically this builds an LDAP filter that means "`sAMAccountName` that does not start with any of the characters `a` through `j`".

If you instead want to *include* only user accounts where the sAMAccountName attribute starts with the letters `a` through `c`, you would use this instead:

```
$charRange = ([Char] 'a'..[Char] 'c') | ForEach-Object { [Char] $_ }
$ldapFilter = "(|"
$charRange | ForEach-Object { $ldapFilter += "(sAMAccountName=$_*)" }
$ldapFilter += ")"
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter $ldapFilter
```

Note that the `&` in the LDAP query is changed to `|` and the `!` is removed.  This LDAP filter means "`sAMAccountName` that starts with any of the characters `a` through `c`".

Comment: Thank you for the help. I wanted to restrict the search of adusers between the letters a to j. How can limit the search of adusers between the letters a to c.