# Use Get ADUser with restriction of three letters in a search in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use get-aduser to print out users from AD restricted to the three letters i am filtering in the script. The script is running, but i do not get any output in the powershell.

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(sAMAccountName>=a)(sAMAccountName<=c))"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering out letters when using get-aduser not working in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46834475/filtering-out-letters-when-using-get-aduser-not-working-in-powershell)

Comment: I already answered this question in the referenced duplicate question.